# Determining if a given subBase S spans a subspace of the given base B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have to design an algorithm which determines if a given subBase S spans a subspace of the given base B. B and S are both given as a list of vectors.

My approach would be to set up a matrix for B and one for S and then determine the rank of those matrices. If S has a rank lower than or equal to the rank of B, then it follows that S spans a subspace of B.

My question is: Does this logic hold or did I forget some properties / did I misunderstand something?

Comment: No. The rank of the matrix for $S$ just gives you the dimension of $\text{span}(S)$. The same for the dimension of $\text{span}(B)$. And, as you know, the fact that the former is smaller (or equal) than the latter does not mean that one subspace is contained in the other: $\dim X\le\dim Y$ does not imply $X\subseteq Y$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I feel like I am missing something quite trivial here. My thought process was as follows: If rank B is for example 3, then the vectors in B span $\mathbb{R}^3$. $\mathbb{R}^3$ has the following subspaces S: The zero-vector, any line through the origin (rank = 1), any plane through the origin (rank = 2) and $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself (rank = 3). I thought that this means that S is a subspace of B. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can I counter it with a better example? If the space is still $\mathbb R^3$ but, say, rank $B$ is $2$, then span of $B$ is a *plane*. You may then have $S$ with the rank $1$, which is a *line*. Now my point is that this line does *not* need to lie on that plane.

Comment: Oh that's true, I didn't think about that. Do you have any hint on how I could approach the problem?

Comment: You can either (a) Check if all the vectors in $S$ are linear combinations of the vectors in $B$ (which is equivalent with solving systems of equations); (b) Check if the span of $B\cup S$ is the same or strictly bigger than the span of $B$. (Find the ranks of matrices made up of $B$ and of $B\cup S$.)

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the quick responses. For approach b): If the span of $B \Cup S$ is bigger than the span of B, that would mean that S is not a subspace of B, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have a implementation which I believe is working. I used the approach suggested in the comments which is as follows:

Take the union of B and S. As B and S are both sets of vectors, this simply means appending the vectors of S to the list B. If B and S were matrices instead, we could add all columns of S to B, given the dimension are compatible.

Testing whether S spans a subspace of B then boils down to testing whether rank of $B \cup S$ is <= than rank of B.

Logic behind this: If S spans a subspace of B, then all vectors in S are already given by a linear combination of vectors in B, so rank of $B \cup S$ is the same as rank of B

Please correct me if anything is wrong about this answer.